# Should I use separate address dimensions?

Tags: database-design, data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling, star-schema

I have a Star Schema model with two Dimensions (User and Store) each of them have addresses, which I store.

Each User and Store can just have one Address. Is it recommended to split the Dimension into a Address Dimension (with a 1:1 relationship)? Are there any technical arguments to handle like this? Or is it a common way to keep the address in the user/store dimension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add the address to the user/store dimension as the address is a property of the dimension member, not the fact record.

Adding the address to the dimension allows you to define attribute relationships between `country -> city -> user` which should improve performance when you create hierarchies using those attributes.

It will usually also allow for easier calculated measures.

As a last point, having the address as attributes on the dimension will allow for easier handling of [slowly changing dimensions](https://www.kimballgroup.com/2008/09/slowly-changing-dimensions-part-2/) if a user/store moves to a new address.

Answer (score 1):

This would be an opinion, but I agree with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43651406) which is along the lines of the question you are asking.  I'm copying the answer from the link here in case the link goes cold.

> It sounds like in the situation you have that you should just include
>   columns for the type of address and the source of the address in the
>   address dimension itself, so it stands alone and you don't have to go
>   via a fact to know what kind of thing it is. You wouldn't need a
>   separate table with keys as you mentioned- the data can safely be
>   denormalised in the dimension.
>
> As an aside:
>
> Although many people do have an address table which is separate, the
>   approach from the Kimball Group would not be to have have 'address' or
>   location dimension as a multi purpose dimension that stands alone- it
>   provides part of what describes something else (like a company, or a
>   customer, or even a 'delivery location'). Instead you'd have the
>   dimension (e.g Customer) and Within that dimension you'd have a number
>   of Address fields, named appropriately (CustomerAddress1,
>   CustomerAddress2, CustomerCity). You may choose to administer the
>   address centrally for convenience behind the scenes, with the other
>   dimensions formed by means of views or further ETL, but in the
>   presentation of the star schema the address table would not be seen
>   separately. The addresses are still conformed in that they're called
>   the same thing and mean the same thing.
>
> However plenty of people go with a separate Address table as you've
>   done